Is there a transparent analog clock widget for Ubuntu Desktop?
Is there a way to put a transparent analog clock on my Desktop that is customisable and that I can make hover on top of other appications so I can comfortably see the time while working or studying?
Did some reserach but couldn't find any so far, only gnome clocks which is not transparent and cannot make it hover on top either.
Thks a lot!

This question is similar to: Any package for clock widget in Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you use X (not Wayland), you can use oclock and wmctrl and get something close to what you want using tools that are easily available in Ubuntu.
Install via apt
sudo apt update
sudo apt install x11-apps wmctrl

Create a shellscript with the following content for example in the directory ~/bin
#!/bin/bash

if wmctrl -l | grep -m1 oclock
then
 pid=$(ps -e |grep oclock | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ .*//')
else
 oclock -transparent -geometry 100x100+0+0 & pid=$!
fi
sleep 1
wid=$(wmctrl -l | grep -m1 oclock | sed 's/ .*//')
#echo "wid of oclock is $wid"
wmctrl -i -r "$wid" -b add,above
#echo "pid of oclock is $pid"
read -p "close oclock now? (y/N) " ans
if [ "$ans" == "y" ]
then
 kill -9 "$pid"
else
 echo "close oclock later with
kill $pid
(or by running this shellscript again and
 answer y when asked to close oclock)"
fi

Let us say you use the name ocl. Make the shellscript executable
chmod +x ~/bin/ocl

Now you can run the shellscript
ocl

and get a transparent clock on top of the other windows.
Please read the manual man oclock to modify the style, size and location of the clock.

An alternative is cairo-clock, if you are willing to install software from external sources.
